# Generically get all object's attributes C++

Tags: c++, c++11

Is there a way to get all of an object's attributes programmatically without having to be class-specific.

Comment: No...................

Comment: What is your problem exactly? Seems to me you are asking about a solution you had in mind, when you should be asking about the problem.

Comment: Assuming that "attributes" are private members of the class, why the HELL would you need to do something like that?!

Comment: Not within your own program.  But you can of course write a program that analyzes another program's source code. Or its own source code, if such is available. Though there is no way for a program to guarantee that the source code it is analyzing is its own.

Comment: No, each class may have different attributes.  You can have a parent object and place all the attributes into a list, then iterate through the list.  Not advisable and most likely, not worth the effort.

Answer (score 2):

yes.. 
for the start you can parse a c++ file ;).. Look at clang..

Depends on what you are trying to achieve - if its reflection you are talking about - no, its not a feature of the language.

Answer (score -1):

No, there is no way to do this, but there should never be a need to in most cases.

Comment: -1 for "never be a need to"... you should study what introspection allows - e.g. see OpenC++ project.  The classic example is effortless serialisation and deserialisation.  Lack of such features is a major shortcoming of C++.

Comment: Introspection allows things, sure, but it's not necessary in most cases.

Comment: You changed your text from *never be a need to* to add *in most cases*, and now feeling hard done by?  "Absolutely necessary" is not a sensible benchmark - C++ is not "absolutely necessary" as you could use C or assembly or a hex editor and machine code.  Introspection would be extremely useful - Stroustrup's spent considerable time designing AST representations for exactly that reason.

Comment: You might want to read what Herb Sutter says about Bjarne's work at http://bytes.com/topic/c/answers/135390-toward-introspection-open-standard - just as evidence of the value.

Comment: @TonyD I changed my answer to reflect your sentiment. Sure, introspection can be useful. All I am saying is you can't do it in C++, but it's ok, because you can refactor your code to do the same thing you were trying to do in a different way. I really wasn't trying to be controversial.